# Rails not able to access Postgresql deployed by Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I have a docker container that spins up my Postgres DB, Elasticsearch, and Redis; however, my rails server is unable to connect to the Postgres DB... The server starts, but when it attempts to connect to the DB, I get the error

```
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
):
```

When Docker launches the DB, it does so on `localhost:5432`. Via the terminal, I'm able to connect to the DB by running `psql -h localhost -U myUser`, but running `psql` results in the same error...

My rails `database.yml` file is configured to connect to the database at `localhost:5432` with `myUser`, but I cannot figure out why it is giving me this error. It seems like Rails is attempting to connect to my Postgres.app server instead of the server Docker is running.

Here is my database.yml file

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgis // I have tried "postgresql" as well
  encoding: unicode
  reconnect: true
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

development: 
  <<: *default
  database: my_db
  username: <my username>
  password: <my password>
```

Here is my .env

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://***:***@novus-postgis-localdev:5432
```

My docker container shows the following

```
ENVIRONMENT: 

DATABASE_URL: postgres://<my username>:<my password>@novus-postgis-localdev:5432
PATH: 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

...

PORTS: 

5432/tcp: 0.0.0.0:5432
5432/tcp: :::5432
```

Therefore, my Rails environment is supposed to connect to my docker DB server, but it appears to be attempting to connect to my Postgres.app server (which isn't running).

What am I missing here / what is wrong with my configurations that have Rails looking at the wrong server?

FWIW, I'm on macOS and I installed Postgres via the Postgres.app.

- When the Postgres.app is running a server, the `psql` command connects to it.
- When the Docker container is running, I am unable to start the Postgres. App server because port 5432 is already used (as expected)

**UPDATE**

I did find out that my Docker DB container is listening on `Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"` whereas my Rails is pointing to the socket `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432`. I am unable to figure out how to change either of these to be the same (rails to look at /var/run/postgresql/... or docker to launch socket at `/tmp/...`

Comment: Where is the application running (in a container?)?  The database (in a separate container?)?  How are you starting these containers (with Docker Compose?)?

Comment: Rails application is not running in a container, just off my local machine. The DB is running in a container on my local machine, which mounts the DB on my local host.

The containers are started with a docker script that starts up the services using `docker-compose`

Answer (score -1):

In the Postgresql configuration file, try and enter,
listen_addresses='*';